# CodeDOM question

Tags: codedom

How to create:

```
internal struct StructName
{
    public static byte[] Code = new byte[] 
    { 
     0, 0, 0, 0 
    };
}
```

in CodeDOM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With out writing the code this should send you in the right direction.

Using **CodeTypeDeclaration** which you would use for making Classes etc has a **IsStruct** property set that to true.

*Where type is = CodeTypeDeclaration.*

That will then enable you to build the first part to make it internal you need to do

**type.Attributes = MemberAttributes.FamilyAndAssembly**; this will make it Internal.

You can then use type.Members.Add() and build up a member to do the rest in the standard way.

Thanks
Alex